# Erroneous clock_t output value on printf

Tags: c, time.h

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t a;

void f(void) {
    a = clock();
    printf("in f(): %g\n", a);
}

void main(void) {
    f();
    printf("in main(): %g\n", a);
}
```

Compiling it with MinGW gcc and running it produces output similar to this:

```
in f(): -1.#QNAN
in main(): 1.49845e-307
```

---

**Question**: Why does `a` contain `-1.#QNAN`? While I understand [what it means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617796/1-qnan-error-c), I do not see what went wrong in the code. At first, I speculated that it has something to do with the printing format specifier for type `clock_t`, but answers from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t) says otherwise. Even to make sure, I did a quick digging in the standard headers and found out that `clock_t` is a typedef for `long` (at least on my machine), which means that there is nothing wrong with regards to displaying the value. Could it be a bug in the `clock()` function?

---

**Edit**: Just after reading the comments, I realized that my actual problem is that I was expecting `a` to be some super small floating-point value so badly that I forgot `clock_t` is, as I said, defined on my machine as of type `long`. Sorry for the bother and thank you all for your time.

Comment: The answer to the other question uses `%g` after converting the value to `double`. You don't seem to do that.

Comment: The type of `clock_t` is unspecified. Therefore `%g` might not be the appropriate format operator: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock_t

Comment: `clock_t` is an integer type, not a `float`, so you cannot use `%g` format to print it, check `printf(3)` documentation for valid format specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Please always take a look at your compiler warning:

```
warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type
      'clock_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
    printf("in f(): %g\n", a);
                    ~~     ^
                    %lu
```

Compiler even tells you how to fix. In short, you can't specify a `double` to `printf()` when the data is `unsigned long`.

Comment: Sorry, that message is CLANG specific, he can be using a compiler that doesn't give such a warning.  Would be better to recommend him to look at `printf(3)` documentation about how to print integer types, like `clock_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`%g` is for printing floating point numbers, but you passed a `clock_t` (which can be any arithmetic type; such as a 32 bit integer).

You need to cast to a `double` if you want to use `%g`:

```
printf("in main(): %g\n", static_cast<double>(a));
```